# Cannot repair Visual Studio after I canceled update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I cancelled updates installation for visual studio community 2017 RC.
Now, i cannot repair or open it. how resolve issue?

I need way to repair without uninstall/Reinstall ,because i have many packages installed on visual studio ,it would removed.

Note:When open visual studio,  i get error "The setup for this Installation was not Complete please run the Installer again to Correct the Issue"

Comment: resolve issue with uninstall/install?

Comment: i need way to repair without uninstall ,because i have many packages installed on visual studio ,it would removed

Comment: You have corrupted *something.* *You* do not know what. The *installer* apparently does not have the intelligence to fix it. Ergo, the *only* safe way is a complete uninstall/reinstall and then install those "many packages" again. Anything else is asking for trouble. Feel free to ignore my advice but, when your doctor tells you to stop poking yourself in the eye with a sharp stick and you continue to do so, don't be surprised if she tells you what she thinks about the wisdom of your choices :-)

Comment: That's why I don't update VS 2017 no more, it ruins everything, it's so stupid, no pause/resume, no selective update, no nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to uninstall and then reinstall because you might mess up the files if try to fix it by yourself and there many reason as to why the updated didn't go as planned. Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

From Program and Features , Select Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 , select Modify ,
and once you have the Screen up , just add or remove some insignificant feature (you can bring it back any time).
Soon you will have the Launch Button. Click to launch VS , remember to remove Auto Update from Options

Comment: Thank you! I didn't feel like reinstalling 17GB worth of junk that is VS2017... long live VS Code

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. It just works!